# Replace integer column to date R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column name Extract date with this value 42037 what is 13/04/2017.

I would like replace the value of the column by the date.

https://aql.datapress.com/leeds/dataset/council-energy-consumption/01042013-to-31032014-kwh-co2.csv

Comment: Edit your question and show a _small_ and _reproducible_ sample of your input data, along with what the expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download the .csv locally.
2. In Excel, right click the column and go to "Format Cells"
3. Pick "Date"
4. The column should turn to dates. Then you just import it in r with:

   data <- read.csv("StackOFQuestion.csv")

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with `as.Date` function by passing the `origin` argument.

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("https://aql.datapress.com/leeds/dataset/council-energy-consumption/01042013-to-31032014-kwh-co2.csv")
as.Date(df$ExtractDate, origin = "1902-03-11")
```